# How to set LANG variable in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, locale

I'm  making an application that supports multi language. And I am using `gettext` and `locale` to solve this issue.

How to set LANG variable in Windows? In Linux and Unix-like systems it's just as simple as

`$ LANG=en_US python appname.py`

And it will automatically set the locale to that particular language. But in Windows, the

`C:\>SET LANG=en_US python appname.py`

or

`C:\>SET LANG=en_US`

`C:\>python appname.py`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows locale support doesn't rely on LANG variable (or, indeed, any other environmental variable). It is whatever the user set it to in Control Panel.

Comment: Applications running on Window might still use the environment variable. In which as the user will be responsible for setting its value. Although your answer was accepted, it doesn't describe how to set the variable in case—which is the actual question.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a batch file like in here: http://www.geany.org/Documentation/FAQ#QQuestions11

```
set LANG=en_US
something.exe
```

or set it through the control panel / system / advanced system settings / advanced / 
environmental variables