# How do I get the computer's current language in Go?

Tags: go, locale, culture

How do I get the computer's current language in Go?

e.g. en-US for USA or es-es for Spain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *nix based systems you can simply use `os.Getenv("LANG")`, I'm not sure if that applies to windows.

//edit

@JimB mentioned that there are other variables to check too, for more details check [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html)

on my system:

```
➜ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: You may wan to also check `LC_*` variables like `LC_MESSAGES`, as they take priority over `LANG`. [gettext for example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Locale-Environment-Variables.html)

Answer (score 2):

Note: [Windows doesn't not rely on `LANG` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180593/6309) (or `LC_*` variables: none are defined on my Windows 8)

The locale is [stored in **`HKCU/ControlPanel/International/LocalName`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775706%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (as mentioned [in this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/da4557b0-dd35-4081-949a-c162843acf71/dos-environment-variable-for-language-reference-on-windows-xp7?forum=ITCG))

[image: localname]

So you are better off using a project accessing the registry, like:

- [`registry/registry.go`](https://code.google.com/p/winsvc/source/browse/registry/registry.go)
- [gowin](https://github.com/luisiturrios/gowin)